# Kotlin multiplatform build desktopApp failure

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

When I run the :desktopApp:packageDistributionForCurrentOS it fails.

Console log:

> Task :desktopApp:createRuntimeImage FAILED
> External tool execution failed:

- Command: [C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe, @C:\Android\Project\desktopApp\build\compose\tmp\createRuntimeImage.args.txt]
- Working dir: []
- Exit code: 2
- Standard output log: C:\Android\Project\desktopApp\build\compose\logs\createRuntimeImage\jlink-2023-06-26-13-28-38-out.txt
- Error log: C:\Android\Project\desktopApp\build\compose\logs\createRuntimeImage\jlink-2023-06-26-13-28-38-err.txt

Standard output file:
Error: --module-path is not specified and this runtime image does not contain jmods directory.
Usage: jlink  --module-path  --add-modules [,...]
Use --help for a list of possible options

Error log file is empty.

Kotlin: 1.8.20
Compose-multiplatform: 1.4.0
Gradle: 8.0

I tried to clean and rebuild the project but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem, I solved it changing Java distribution.
I have the problem with OpenJDK from RedHat 17.0.7 (packaged with Fedora) and move to Eclipse Temurin release (17.0.8). Not sure if you still have the problem, but I leave this answer it for someone else has similar issue and maybe can help.

I know that you are on Windows, but maybe is a similar issue in jbr jdk version.